# build array of only one property when condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am looking to filter an array of only one property from the filtered items.

I currently have:

```
  let tools = permissions.filter(perm => {
    if (perm.state === state) return perm.tool;
  });
```

and that builds an array of perm objects. I am looking to have tools only filled with perm.tool. Is this possible?

example:

```
permissions = 
[ 
{ 
    state: 'NJ', 
    tool: 'email'
}, 
{ 
    state: 'MA', 
    tool: 'print'
}, 
{ 
    state: 'NJ', 
    tool: 'submit claim'
}, 
]
```

When `state = 'NJ'` , I am looking to get:

```
tools = ['email', 'submit claim']
```

Comment: can you post a input/output example ?

Comment: Does perm.tool return a boolean? I think you're misusing the filter. Filter iterates over the array and expects a boolean value to be returned and returns a new array.

Comment: @Bren With that being said, I also believe I may be misusing filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a reduce

```
let tools = permissions.reduce((results, perm) => {
  if (perm.state === state) {
    results.push(perm.tool);
  }
  return results;
}, []);
```

Comment: Much more elegant solution to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `map` after the `filter`:

```
let tools = permissions
                .filter(perm => perm.state === state)
                .map( el => el.tool );
```

Comment: That will put an undefined in the array where perm.state !== state

Comment: I tried this prior to my example above. The only issue is, wherever the condition is not met , the value in the array is undefined

Comment: A filter followed by a map should be done in a single reduce rather than iterating the collection twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
let tools = (state) => {
  return (permissions.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  if (rec.state === state) {
    return [...acc, rec.tool]
  }
    return [...acc]
  }, [])
  )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a solution:

```js
const permissions = [ 
  { 
      state: 'NJ', 
      tool: 'email'
  }, 
  { 
      state: 'MA', 
      tool: 'print'
  }, 
  { 
      state: 'NJ', 
      tool: 'submit claim'
  }
];

function getTools(state) {
   const tools = [];
   permissions.forEach(perm => {
     if(perm.state == state) {
       tools.push(perm.tool)
     }
   });
   return tools;
}

console.log(getTools('NJ'));
```

Comment: That only returns the first result

Comment: Oh right. I misinterpreted the question. Let me fix it.